# How to get the information about the status of data receiving and sending in ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, utilities

Is there any tools to get the information about status of data receiving and sending in Ethernet (Real-time information is better, GUI tools is better)?

The information includes:

sending and receiving rate (Mbps) 
total data sending and receiving since start the machine (this is optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several available. A full-fledged network tool is `iptraf` (http://iptraf.seul.org/).

Otherwise, `nload` is a tool that just shows network bandwidth usage, in a simple and neat way.

If you want to run network benchmarks, look for `netserver`/`netperf` or `iperf`.

Comment: Thanks, however what are the dependencies of iptraf?

Comment: According to the (out-of-date) docs at http://iptraf.seul.org/download.html `iptraf` is also available as RPM and DEB package, so you just let the Package Manager take care of that.

Comment: Thank you so much, are there any other project which is still under maintenance?

Comment: Do you mean "maintained"? I think the others project I mentioned are currently maintained, I haven't checked though.